# Most efficient way of using Java's DES implementation to encrypt a single (64 bit) block?

Tags: java, performance, des

I have a method that encrypts a single (64 bit) block using Java's DES implementation.

```
public BitSet encrypt(BitSet plaintextBlock, BitSet key)
{
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        SecretKeyFactory sf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        Key desKey = sf.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(key.toByteArray()));
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        byte[] input = plaintextBlock.toByteArray();
        byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(input);

        return BitSet.valueOf(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* Exception handling omitted */ }
}
```

The `plainTextBlock` will always be less than or equal to 64 bits. Padding and Chaining are implemented separately. This works fine, but turns out to run very slowly.

So my question is: **Is there a more efficient way of encrypting a single block with Java's DES?**

Comment: I am testing it with a byte array against a non-optimized custom implementation with the same key and data, and it is more than twice as slow.

Comment: And that's after I split the first half of the method (up until getting the `KeyFactory`) into the constructor.